# SQL returning all rows in one table where a column valule is equal to matching column value joined to another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

For an example  lets say I have table INFO that contains columns:

ID - Name - Address

I also have a second table PURCHASES that contains columns:

Region - Name  -  Purchases

Multiple people can be in the same region, but each person only has one ID.

I want to write a query that will, based on a given ID in the INFO table, return all the rows in PURCHASES of people who live in the same region as the person with the specified ID.

I have done an Inner Join on Name for the two tables but can't figure out the best way to write a query.

Edit: My main problem is that there is no Region column in INFO. The only way to get the region is by joining to the PURCHASES table. Then I need the results of all rows containing that Region.

Comment: You haven't included the table which stores which region an INFO lives in, nor have you included your existing query...

Comment: Can you show what you wrote please?

Comment: Is your ID field in table INFO refers to(acts as a foreign key for) Region in purchases table?

Comment: No, the Id field is just the key for the INFO table and then the PURCHASES table only has Name which is matching INFO.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want but you could probably twik it a bit to better fit your needs:

```
SELECT
    Purchasse
FROM
    PURCHASSE
INNER JOIN
    INFO ON INFO.Name = PURCHASSE.Name
WHERE 
    INFO.ID = yourID
```

This should give you `Purchasse` for any given `ID` that the `Name` match for the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Select * from PURCHASES LEFT OUTER JOIN INFO ON PURCHASES.NAME = INFO.NAME WHERE INFO.ID = givenID